# R: To identify whether column names in a dataframe contains string

Tags: r, dataframe, r-colnames

Say I have 2 dataframes:

df1:

```
Name  Data123   Data321   Age
A     123       321       20
```

df2:

```
Name   Age
B      20
```

I wish to check which dataframe has column names containing the string "Data". If yes, the dataframe will be passed into a customized function as a whole. Thus in this case I wish to only have df1 passed into the said function. Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a function with `grepl` for reusability (from `base R`), wrap with `any` to return a single TRUE/FALSE (if there is a column name with the substring 'Data' or not) and this can be used for the purpose mentioned

```
f1 <- function(dat, pat) any(grepl(pat, names(dat)))
f1(df1, '^Data')
f1(df2, '^Data')
```

Or with `startsWith`

```
f1 <- function(dat, pat) any(startsWith(names(dat), pat))
f1(df1, 'Data')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str_detect()` from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
#does any (column) name inside df1 contains "Data"?
any(str_detect(names(df1), "Data"))
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name = "A", Data123 = 123, Data321 = 321, Age = 20)
df2 <- data.frame(Name = "B", Age = 20)
```